# Sending Mail in java

Tags: jakarta-mail

Hi i want to send mail using below code, if it is executed, it will thrown an exception given below what i need to do..I am using java,eclipse,i have added javaMailAPI jars also....do i need additional jars to this programme.

```
    package firstpackage;

    /*public class SendMail {  }*/

    import java.util.Properties;
    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.MessagingException;
    import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Transport;
    import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
    import org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils;

    public class SendMail {
      public SendMail(String fromMail, String tomail)
      {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
    "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("Email_Id","password");
          }
        });
      try {
          Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
          message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromMail));
          message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
          InternetAddress.parse(tomail));
          message.setSubject("Script failed");
          //message.setText("your test has failed for script name:Name of your scipt <============================>"+ ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e) );
          Transport.send(message);
          System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
          throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
      }

      public static void main(String args[])
      {
        new SendMail("memusipra4@gmail.com","spmukalla@gmail.com");
      }
    }
```

and exception is:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: Unable to locate provider for protocol: smtp
        at firstpackage.SendMail.<init>(SendMail.java:42)
        at firstpackage.SendMail.main(SendMail.java:48)
    Caused by: javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: Unable to locate provider for protocol: smtp

     at javax.mail.Session.getProvider(Session.java:237)
            at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:346)
            at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:376)
            at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:67)
            at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:48)
            at firstpackage.SendMail.<init>(SendMail.java:39)
            ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll want to fix these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes), although they aren't the source of your problem.

Did you follow [these instructions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#libeclipse) to add JavaMail to your project?

Try running your program outside of Eclipse, e.g., by packaging your application in a jar file and then using "java -cp SendMail.jar:javax.mail.jar firstpackage.SendMail".